# How to trigger onclick event on Checkbox inside TableColumn in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I have defined TableColumn with checkbox type like below in Javafx.

```
TableColumn<MyObject, Boolean> cbCol = new TableColumn<>(strColName);
cbCol.setCellFactory(CheckBoxCellFactory.forTableColumn(cbCol));
```

Now I need to trigger onclick event(to perform some operation) on any of the checkbox clicked inside TableColumn.  Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the below custome cell factory to get `checkboxes` in the `tableCell`. You can use the same and have the `onClick` listener here as well. Below is the code:

```
final class BooleanCell extends TableCell<MyObject, Boolean> {

private CheckBox checkBox;

public BooleanCell() {
    checkBox = new CheckBox();
    checkBox.setOnAction((evt) -> {

         getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()).setCheck(new SimpleBooleanProperty(checkBox.isSelected()));

        }
    });
    this.setGraphic(checkBox);
    this.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    this.setEditable(true);
}

@Override
public void startEdit() {
    super.startEdit();
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    checkBox.requestFocus();
}

@Override
public void cancelEdit() {
    super.cancelEdit();
//            checkBox.setDisable(true);
}

@Override
public void commitEdit(Boolean value) {
    super.commitEdit(value);
//            checkBox.setDisable(true);
}

@Override
public void updateItem(Boolean item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (empty) {
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        if (item != null) {
            checkBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            checkBox.setSelected(item);
        }
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setGraphic(checkBox);
    }
}
}
```

The above `cell factory` can be applied to the `tableColumn` as mentioned below.

```
    Callback<TableColumn<MyObject, Boolean>, TableCell<MyObject, Boolean>> booleanCellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn<MyObject, Boolean>, TableCell<MyObject, Boolean>>() {
                @Override
                public TableCell<MyObject, Boolean> call(TableColumn<MyObject, Boolean> p) {
                    return new BooleanCell();
                }
            };

tbColCheck.setCellFactory(booleanCellFactory);
```